# Linux Mint stops suddenly, seems to be halted but is still working. I can't log into the desktop

Tags: linux-mint

I have an issue with linux mint: after 32 minutes my computer halts the monitor (dual monitors) and I can't log into desktop. But if I use ssh to enter the computer is still working.

This are the logs of running processes and Linux Mint Version:

RELEASE=18
CODENAME=sarah
EDITION="Xfce 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
DESKTOP=Xfce
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_xfce_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_xfce.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=help:linuxmint
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 18 Xfce 64-bit

Full log is on: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YSLP7-JET9DQn5gpxpGoccK1rdsIrTS9KkCOG6ZubSQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Finally I solved, the issue was a qt5 python lib:

sudo apt-get remove python3-pyqt5

Comment: Not solved yet... seems to be xserver xorg - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze